# Select distinct column values in a single row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have the below requirement.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Abc     02      03      02      05      07
```

When I select this row, I should get the values like below

```
Abc 02 03 05 07 <null>
```

The duplicates should get eliminated but the columns should remain as it is.

Appreciate your help!!

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: I am actually looking for the way to write sql. I have no idea.

Comment: How do you have a current result without using a query?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - that is not a "current result" - that is the DESIRED result. Not from a query, but from requirements.

Comment: @Sr.TechnicalSpecialist - are you looking to update the values in the columns themselves? Something is not clear - if the value in column 4 is a duplicate, you want to move the values from the remaining columns "one column to the left" and insert a NULL in the LAST column?

Comment: @mathguy. Yes that is correct. I have to shift the values by eliminating duplicates and nulls in the last columns.

Comment: OK. Data types? I see col1 is string (varchar2, whatever); can we assume col2 - col6 are also string (varchar2)? You will run into serious difficulties if they can be of different data types.

Comment: All are varachar2 datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing data in columns that should be in rows.  The data structure should really look like this:

```
column1 number value
  ABC     1      02
  ABC     2      03
  ABC     3      02
. . .
```

Then your query would be easy.  You can get the values you want by unpivoting:

```
select distinct column1, value
from (select column1, column2 as valuefrom t union all
      select column1, column3 from t union all
      select column1, column4 . . .
     ) x;
```

You can get them as a list using:

```
select column1, listagg(value, ', ') within group (order by value)
from (select column1, column2 as valuefrom t union
      select column1, column3 from t union
      select column1, column4 . . .
     ) x
group by column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I put everything (including base tables) into a single query, so others can play with it - test it, find better approaches, etc. In real life, what I call "t" (the second cte, or common table expression) is the starting table, and what I call "c" (the first cte) should exist somewhere as a table or a view, or it can be built on the fly as I did. REQUIREMENT: The number, names, and ordering of all the columns in table t must be known beforehand, they cannot be dynamic (unless one wants to rewrite this using dynamic SQL).

Note also that it would be much easier if I could assume all column names were upper case. I didn't want to assume it, so the code looks more complicated with the upper(...) - because Oracle WILL change column names to upper case when it unpivots (or else I would have to do even more work...)

I return the result in a new "table" format (and this can be used if t has more than one row - the output is an equal number of rows). I didn't write it in "update t..." format; that should be relatively easy to do if needed. I couldn't tell if "I have to shift the values" means in place (i.e. update) or if it means in the output compared to the input.

Here is what the input table (one row only) looks like:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2    COLUMN3    COLUMN4    COLUMN5    COLUMN6
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Abc        02         03         02         05         07
```

The output:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2    COLUMN3    COLUMN4    COLUMN5    COLUMN6
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Abc        02         03         05         07
```

And the code:

```
with c (col_rank, col_name) as (select 1, upper('Column1') from dual union all
                                select 2, upper('Column2') from dual union all
                                select 3, upper('Column3') from dual union all
                                select 4, upper('Column4') from dual union all
                                select 5, upper('Column5') from dual union all
                                select 6, upper('Column6') from dual          ),
     t (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6) as 
                         (select 'Abc', '02', '03', '02', '05', '07' from dual),
     x as (select * from t unpivot (col_value for col_name in (Column1, 
                                 Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6))),
     y as (select col_rank, col_name, col_value from x natural join c),
     z as (select col_rank, col_value, 
                  case when col_value in (select y1.col_value from y y1 
                                          where y1.col_rank < y2.col_rank) then 0 
                                                          else 1 end flag from y y2),
     u as (select col_value, 
                  count(flag) over (order by col_rank rows between unbounded preceding 
                                       and current row) val_rank from z where flag = 1)
select * from (select col_name, col_value from c left outer join u 
                                                  on c.col_rank = u.val_rank )
pivot (min(col_value) for col_name in (upper('Column1') Column1, upper('Column2') Column2,
                                       upper('Column3') Column3, upper('Column4') Column4, 
                                       upper('Column5') Column5, upper('Column6') Column6))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ) AS
SELECT 'abc', '02', '03', '02', '05', '07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', '05', '04', '02', '03', '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

**Query - Not using a user-defined function**:

```
SELECT MAX( col1 ) AS col1,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN value END ) AS col2,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN value END ) AS col3,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN value END ) AS col4,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 4 THEN value END ) AS col5,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 5 THEN value END ) AS col6
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.rid ORDER BY v.column_value) AS rn,
         v.COLUMN_VALUE AS value
  FROM   ( SELECT col1,
                  ROWID AS rid, 
                  SET( stringlist( col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ) ) AS cols
           FROM   table_name ) t,
           TABLE( t.cols ) v
)
GROUP BY rid;
```

**Query - Using a UDF**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nth_item(
  collection STRINGLIST,
  n          INT
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  IF collection IS NULL OR n < 1 OR n > collection.COUNT THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN collection(n);
END;
/
```

Then:

```
SELECT col1,
       nth_item( cols, 1 ) AS col2,
       nth_item( cols, 2 ) AS col3,
       nth_item( cols, 4 ) AS col4,
       nth_item( cols, 4 ) AS col5,
       nth_item( cols, 5 ) AS col6
FROM   (
  SELECT  col1,
          SET( stringlist( col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ) ) AS cols
  FROM    table_name
);
```

**Output (for both queries)**:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
abc  02   03   05   07
abc  01   02   03   04   05
abc  01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  tbl as (
    select  'Abc' Column1, '02' Column2, '03' Column3,  '02' Column4, '03' Column5, '07' Column6, 1 rrowid from dual union all 
    select  'Dfg' Column1, '10' Column2, '10' Column3,  '10' Column4, '10' Column5, '10' Column6, 2 rrowid from dual
  ),
  unpv as (
    select *
    from tbl
    unpivot (val FOR col IN (column1 AS 1, column2 AS 2, column3 AS 3, column4 AS 4, column5 as 5, column6 as 6))
  ),
  clc as (
    select rrowid, val, row_number() over (partition by rrowid order by col) col
    from (
      select rrowid, col,
        decode(row_number() over (partition by rrowid, val order by col), 1, val, null) val
      from unpv
    )
    where not val is null)
select * from clc
pivot  (max(val) AS val FOR (col) IN (1 AS a, 2 AS b, 3 AS c, 4 as d, 5 as e, 6 as f));
```

Result is:

```
    RROWID A_VAL B_VAL C_VAL D_VAL E_VAL F_VAL
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
         1 Abc   02    03    07          
         2 Dfg   10
```